# Android DialogFragment Progress

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to create a horizontal progress dialog in a async of a utils class.. It creates the dialog but when my file is downloading it does not update the progress.

Here is my progress dialog setup:

```
public static class DownloadProgressDialog extends DialogFragment {
    private String title;

    public DownloadProgressDialog(String string) {
        this.title = string;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setTitle(R.string.dialog_download_progress_title);
        String format = getString(R.string.dialog_download_progress_message);
        String text = String.format(format, title);
        progressDialog.setMessage(text);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        return progressDialog;
    }
}
```

This is how my async class publishes the results:

```
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                publishProgress((int)(total*100/length));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
```

and how it updates:

```
    public void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        progressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }
```

anything else you need to see let me know, thank you in advance!

here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: you did not included publishProgress(String progress) code .

Comment: Where do you declare dialog?

Comment: Is the `onProgressUpdate` method called ?